# Ubuntu on 2013 iMac 27" with Fusion Drive?

Tags: mac

I know I could trawl the internet for information about how well the iMac 2003 runs on Ubuntu but every time I've bought a new iMac all the problems everyone reported failed to materialize for me, possibly as we get the later models in Oz or the users are a little less technical, I'm not sure.

So the internet trawl is not very reliable for information. (Have owned 4 different iMacs)

Any Ubuntu folk out there running the current model? What are the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running the new MacBook Pro with a multi-boot of Mountain Lion, Ubuntu 12.04, and Windows 7. Not exactly the same deal, but my machine works amazing otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I have a Mac book Air, and apart from the terrible battery drain on sleep I'm happy with that as well. Does your MAcBook Pro have a fusion drive? Do the special ports work?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I've never really looked over the Drive specs. The ports work fine, there's no real problems overall.

Comment: @Doogfar I looked, It's a SSD that is directly connected to the motherboard.

Comment: @sharksfan98 did you set up a (BYO) Fusion Drive on your MacBook Pro?  (See my warning, below!)

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: [Ubuntu BROKE my BYO Fusion Drive, almost irreparably](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519380/is-ubuntu-still-toxic-to-macs-with-fusion-drive).  That question link details what went wrong and how I fixed it.  Be sure you have complete, current backups, including a record of exactly how your drives are partitioned before trying.  And update this question with the results if you did try.