# Is Ubuntu still toxic to Macs with Fusion Drive?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mac, lvm, macbook-pro

Installing Ubuntu BROKE my (since-repaired) [Fusion Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_Drive).

I burned `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso` to a DVD, and booted it and I asked it to install beside my OSX install on my homemade* Fusion Drive on my `MacBookPro4,1`.

Instead, it created a Linux swap partition (disk0s5), a **non**-bootable (even via rEFInd) partition (disk0s4) of the new [new Linux filesystem data partition type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#endnote_linwinb), and made my OSX install NON-BOOTABLE by CHANGING the partition type  of half of my fusion drive to FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF.  I revived my system by [changing the partition type back to Apple CoreStorage](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6490170)

I can find nothing in the [Release Notes Change Summary for 14.04.1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/14.04.1) to suggest a better result is likely due to a bug fix in .1.

So, **any tips for how to make rEFInd boot the Ubuntu install on my disk0s4?**  (Or otherwise get Ubuntu installed safely beside my existing OSX Fusion Drive?)  TIA.

I already tried creating `/EFI/refind/drivers_x64/` and putting `ext2_x64.efi` in it.
My refind.conf is still in the default config.  I can't mount disk0s4.

--

*My homemade Fusion Drive has been working well for many months; yes it really works; I get the speedup and it keeps 4GB free on the SSD and moves stuff, as shown by `iostat -w9`.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to install a 2.5 years old version of Ubuntu?

Comment: No.  (See the edit history for the question - http://askubuntu.com/posts/519380/revisions)  I'm not sure if I used 12.04 or 14.04; I've downloaded both, the former a long time ago.  I did the install last month, but when I was writing the question, I realized I'm not sure which one I used.

Comment: @noleti, I reverted the edit.  I found the DVD and regained access to the DVD drive I used to do the install and it is indeed 14.04 - a recent version of Ubuntu.  Sorry for the slow response and confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS works fine on a fusion drive. However, make sure you partition the drive using the installer and **do not** use the Mac version of the Ubuntu ISO. The regular version supports EFI booting which also negates the need for rEFInd.

By installing in EFI mode, Ubuntu will be available as a boot option by holding down the Option key on startup. Also, do not add any additional partitions for example, SWAP. Only create one system partition for Ubuntu since Fusion drives only support one additional partition.

Here's a short clip showing Ubuntu being selected on startup on my MacBook Pro without rEFInd and natively booting via EFI:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0RM3L8r4cE